# crop free hand selected part of image

Tags: android, image

I wants to add cropping fature in my ANDROID app. I know there are deafault cropping feature available in gallery but in them only rectangular or circular selection of area is possible. I wants to selected any part of image with free hand and them crop the selected part of image from original image. for example selecting head part of an complete human picture and then crop it. See below what i wants.

BEFORE

[image]

AFTER

[image]

Please help me and also sugest if any free lib is there.

Thanks

Comment: Did you figure out solution for for this question..??

Comment: did you get any solution for free handed crop?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the library I used once:
[Android widget for cropping and rotating an image.](https://github.com/edmodo/cropper)

To add the Cropper to your application, specify `com.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView` in your layout XML

```
<com.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView 
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/CropImageView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Or you can modify attributes programmatically.
See the [WIKI](https://github.com/edmodo/cropper/wiki) here.

Comment: Thanks Captaindroid, I have already gone through suggested solution but did not find it working as my requirements. Do you know any other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.DashPathEffect;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Build.VERSION;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HandsCropView extends View implements OnTouchListener {
    static Bitmap bitmap;
    public static List<Point> points;
    int C_H_Point;
    int C_W_Point;
    int DIST = 2;
    int D_height;
    int D_width;
    boolean NutralButton = false;
    boolean bfirstpoint = false;
    int canvasHeight;
    int canvasWidth;
    boolean flgPathDraw = true;
    Bitmap img;
    int img_height;
    int img_width;
    LayoutParams layoutParams;
    Context mContext;
    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.0f;
    Point mfirstpoint = null;
    Point mlastpoint = null;
    private Paint paint;
    Paint tectcolor = new Paint();

    private class ScaleListener extends SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        private ScaleListener() {
        }

        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            HandsCropView.this.mScaleFactor = HandsCropView.this.mScaleFactor * detector.getScaleFactor();
            HandsCropView.this.mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(HandsCropView.this.mScaleFactor, 5.0f));
            HandsCropView.this.invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }

    public HandsCropView(Context c, Bitmap image) {
        super(c);
        bitmap = image;
        this.img_width = bitmap.getWidth();
        this.img_height = bitmap.getHeight();
        System.out.println("img_width" + this.img_width + "img_height" + this.img_height);
        DisplayMetrics metrics1 = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        this.D_width = metrics1.widthPixels;
        this.D_height = metrics1.heightPixels;
        if (this.img_width <= this.D_width) {
            this.C_W_Point = this.D_width - this.img_width;
        }
        if (this.img_height <= this.D_height) {
            this.C_H_Point = this.D_height - this.img_height;
        }
        this.mContext = c;
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        this.paint = new Paint(1);
        this.paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        this.paint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{10.0f, 20.0f}, 5.0f));
        this.paint.setStrokeWidth(5.0f);
        this.paint.setColor(-1);
        if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= 15) {
            setLayerType(1, this.paint);
        }
        this.paint.setShadowLayer(5.5f, 6.0f, 6.0f, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        this.layoutParams = new LayoutParams(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        setOnTouchListener(this);
        points = new ArrayList<>();
        this.bfirstpoint = false;
        this.mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(c, new ScaleListener());
    }

    public HandsCropView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.mContext = context;
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        this.paint = new Paint(1);
        this.paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        this.paint.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);
        setOnTouchListener(this);
        points = new ArrayList<>();
        this.bfirstpoint = false;
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.scale(this.mScaleFactor, this.mScaleFactor);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0.0f, 0.0f, null);
        Path path = new Path();
        boolean first = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i += 2) {
            Point point = (Point) points.get(i);
            if (first) {
                first = false;
                path.moveTo((float) point.x, (float) point.y);
            } else if (i < points.size() - 1) {
                Point next = (Point) points.get(i + 1);
                path.quadTo((float) point.x, (float) point.y, (float) next.x, (float) next.y);
            } else {
                this.mlastpoint = (Point) points.get(i);
                path.lineTo((float) point.x, (float) point.y);
            }
        }
        canvas.drawPath(path, this.paint);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        Point point = new Point();
        point.x = (int) event.getX();
        point.y = (int) event.getY();
        if (this.flgPathDraw) {
            if (this.bfirstpoint) {
                if (comparepoint(this.mfirstpoint, point)) {
                    points.add(this.mfirstpoint);
                    this.flgPathDraw = false;
                    GetValue();
                } else if (point.x <= this.img_width && point.y <= this.img_height) {
                    points.add(point);
                }
            } else if (point.x <= this.img_width && point.y <= this.img_height) {
                points.add(point);
            }
            if (!this.bfirstpoint) {
                this.mfirstpoint = point;
                this.bfirstpoint = true;
            }
        } else {
            this.mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        invalidate();
        Log.e("Hi  ==>", "Size: " + point.x + " " + point.y);
        if (event.getAction() == 1) {
            this.mlastpoint = point;
            if (this.flgPathDraw && points.size() > 12 && !comparepoint(this.mfirstpoint, this.mlastpoint)) {
                this.flgPathDraw = false;
                points.add(this.mfirstpoint);
                GetValue();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean comparepoint(Point first, Point current) {
        int left_range_y = current.y - 3;
        int right_range_x = current.x + 3;
        int right_range_y = current.y + 3;
        if (current.x - 3 >= first.x || first.x >= right_range_x || left_range_y >= first.y || first.y >= right_range_y || points.size() < 10) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void fillinPartofPath() {
        Point point = new Point();
        point.x = ((Point) points.get(0)).x;
        point.y = ((Point) points.get(0)).y;
        points.add(point);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void resetView() {
        points.clear();
        this.paint.setColor(-1);
        this.paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        this.flgPathDraw = true;
        invalidate();
    }

    public static boolean GetValue() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean getBooleanValue() {
        return this.NutralButton;
    }
}
```

Comment: where you get this cropping function? Any library source or manually written